# Difference between COUNT and SUM within an Aggregate CASE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Full disclosure, I am learning and I have searched all over the internet and I just can't figure out my question.

I am working on an online class and was given the following example:

```
select 
     DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, MONTH(OrderDate), -1)) AS  'Month',
     SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(OrderDate) = 2005 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Orders,
     SUM(CASE YEAR(OrderDate) WHEN 2005 THEN Totaldue ELSE 0 END) AS 'Total Value'
from
    sales.salesorderheader
group by Month(orderdate)
order by Month(orderdate) ASC
```

That returns the following results:

[image: Results 1]

I understood that (I thought) so I began messing around with the code to further understand Case statements. Looking at the code I thought that the Orders field was essentially finding all the orders in a month, assigning a 1 to each one, and then adding them all up. Because each one was assigned a 1 I figured that I could change the SUM to COUNT and I would get the same results.

However, this code:

```
select 
     DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, MONTH(OrderDate), -1)) AS  'Month',
     COUNT(CASE WHEN YEAR(OrderDate) = 2005 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Orders,
     SUM(CASE YEAR(OrderDate) WHEN 2005 THEN Totaldue ELSE 0 END) AS 'Total Value'
from
    sales.salesorderheader
group by Month(orderdate)
order by Month(orderdate) ASC
```

Returns these results:

[image: Results 2]

To try and break this down I created a query that would just look for the orders in January 2005 and count them.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
WHERE OrderDate >= '1/1/2005' AND OrderDate < '1/1/2005'
```

This returned 0. The same as the SUM query. I get that COUNT counts rows and SUM sums numbers in a column, but I just don't understand the results I'm getting. Could someone please explain why the count query is returning 2483 for January and not 0?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For [`COUNT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/count-transact-sql) 1 and 0 are the same. What you really need is `NULL`:

> COUNT(ALL expression) evaluates expression for each row in a group and returns the number of **nonnull values**.

```
select 
   DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, MONTH(OrderDate), -1)) AS  'Month',
   COUNT(CASE WHEN YEAR(OrderDate) = 2005 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Orders,
   SUM(CASE YEAR(OrderDate) WHEN 2005 THEN Totaldue ELSE 0 END) AS 'Total Value'
from sales.salesorderheader
group by Month(orderdate)
order by Month(orderdate) ASC;
```

Or even shorter(default `ELSE` is `NULL` so we could omit that part)

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN YEAR(OrderDate) = 2005 THEN 1 END) AS Orders,
```

---

Example:

```
              SUM         COUNT         COUNT
2005           1            1             1
2006           0            0            NULL
2007           0            0            NULL
2005           1            1             1
===============================================
               2            4             2
```

Comment: Ahhh when I change the ELSE to NULL I get my expected result. Thanks! I still have a question though, where are the order counts coming from? If there were no orders in January how is it assigning a 0 to a record to be counted?

Comment: @Talbert1209 You probably have orders in that months from years different than 2005. try to use `from sales.salesorderheader where YEAR(order_date) = 2005 ...` and you won't get these months.

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much, @lad2025

Answer (score 0):

When you use count(*) you count ALL the rows. If you want to count how many orders you have, you have to use a column: eg: count(OrderDate). Try it

Answer (score 0):

**count example:**
assume that your column has 3 value and column name is the order

2 ---------- 5 ---------- 4----- Null

now if you run

`count (order)`

it will return = 3 how many entries you have in the column without null

**sum example:**

2 ---------- 5 ---------- 4

now if you run

`sum (order)`

it will return = 2+5+4=11  its add all the entries